# Android Wear fullscreen alarm

Tags: android, wear-os, android-alarms, android-wear-notification

Is it possible that my Wear application sets an alarm on my watch that is shown above all notifications in fullscreen mode, e.g. like the stock clock alarm does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the AlarmManager on the watch works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Send Message using [Message API](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html) from wear to mobile.

`OnMessageReceive()`(on the phone) open Activity (fullscreen) that you want. Using:
`startActivity(new Intent(this, YourFullscreenActivityHere.class););`

Comment: Damn, i got a typo in my question! I wanted the wear app to set a alarm on the watch, not the phone. However i solved it by using the AlarmManager! Thanks anyway!

Comment: I have to wait for 12 hours before I can do that.